# Errors in call method in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am a beginer in typescript and trying to impliment this piece of code but getting 2 errors in line number 3. It is showing name and address not defined. Can anybody help me to make this code workable.

```
var company = {
    fullName: function(ceo :string, teamcount :string) :string {
        return "Name :- " + this.name + "\nAddress:- " + this.address + "\nCEO :- " + ceo + "\nTeamCount :- " + teamcount;
        }
    }

var company1 = {
    name:"BOB the builder",
    address: "Disney world"
}


const temporaryVariable = company.fullName.call(company1,"BOB","30")
console.log(temporaryVariable)
```

Comment: Can you shed some context as to where you are trying to run this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per definition

> The call() method calls a function with a given `this` value and
> arguments provided individually.

`this` is the current context and can be used to extend the properties, but you can't pass an object in its place.

The easiest way to do is to add the object as a param in your function like

```
var company = {
    fullName: function(data: any,ceo :string, teamcount :string) :string {
        return "Name :- " + data.name + "\nAddress:- " + data.address + "\nCEO :- " + ceo + "\nTeamCount :- " + teamcount;
        }
    }
```

and then update your `call` to below

```
const temporaryVariable = company.fullName.call(this, company1, "BOB","30");
```

Comment: You 100% can pass an object in.  When you pass an object in 'this' references the object you pass in.  In fact his code works as is:  https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-bll0tn

Comment: No, your module in code sandbox is `commonJS`, the OP won't work in `ESNext` module. My answer is strict to typescript module as OP described

Comment: OP needs to setup his environment  which is exactly what my answer says

Comment: lol why, he is running pure typescript. :D

Comment: Your answer is totally incorrect about .call

Comment: Its not, please remember JS and typescript are different

Comment: Maybe a link to the differences between .call in typescript and js would help in that case

Comment: Thanks tushar for the help your answer works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var company = {
fullName: function(ceo :string, teamcount :string) :string {
    return "Name :- " + this.name + "\nAddress:- " + this.address + "\nCEO :- " + ceo + "\nTeamCount :- " + teamcount;
    }
}
```

In this object, fullName needs to have access to the name and address variable at any time no matter in which context you are calling it.

And as the **company** object doesn't have those variables, this will try to look immediate next scope to find those variables, which may or may not exist, and that's why TS complains about that [Remember you may not want to break the code during run time, since name and address may not be found].

For example:
In both below cases, Even if TS shows errors,
it does work fine for your code, check logs of [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAxg9gtgBxAOwJ4QLwQN4CgIEQBmArgDZkByIcApgFzEnJQAuAljMgBRS0wR6AZ1Zh2yAOYAaCK1o1YzVoJFjJAShWjxEnPkIGwtViTDIIAImp1BAWksQA1LIAW7IQDpkNWk8sAdZABBABMQoyEhensLP1Y3TxAwiKE-C0CAYQBRAHk7B2c%20AWd05AAVeTgMmCV82Oc5BRrkVgBufQMCAF8OiB7cUEhYRBRUAEZMPQNvOnoLACEc%20ddfACNydhDaMAspXqTw2kjGCwARd2RadAB3GDAyEItcftxYZBFZWkQ78FQANXA7BAqzIviwwyQaA8pAo1loHigIAovHgkPGUgWS12FgAzAAGCzqV5cIQwUEeMgwCTcOTfMC-AFiYGg9RAA)

However, it doesn't work when you run it in [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAxg9gtgBxAOwJ4QLwQN4CgIEQBmArgDZkByIcApgFzEnJQAuAljMgBRS0wR6AZ1Zh2yAOYAaCK1o1YzVoJFjJAShWjxEnPkIGDYWqxJhkEAETU6ggLRWIAalkALdkIB0yGrWdWAHWQAQQATUOMhIXoHS39Wdy8QcMihf0sggGEAUQB5e0cXPgEXDOQAFXk4TJglAriXOQVa5FYAbn1DCABfTp7cXFBIWEQUVABGTD0DORF6SwAhXIW3PwAjcnZQ2jBLKT6uWgBZGGMAERI4OFQANXB2EDWyBiszj2RadAB3U7JQy1wvQGsGQIlktEQp3At3uj2eUxGSDQnlIFBstE8UBAFF48CREyki2We0sAGYAAyWdS4EFCGDPTxkGASbhySFgaF3MRw2jqIA) case

So, use the TS for the purpose it is supposed to use (Prevent bugs before run time)

You may want to refactor it like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAxg9gtgBxAOwJ4QLwQN4CgIEQBmArgDZkByIcApgFzEnJQAuAljMgBTbI20ANBBAATUWFoBnKcKi0Yw1rRqxmrAL6M8hXRH51GU1mHbIA5gG58egmInSpRk2as3b8mM9MXrtgsqqMOrern6EGgCUoRY47nqSrCRgyBAARNR0EPQAtOkQANT6AoXpADrIAILikjK5%20UX2tVKlaRUAwgCiAPLZeWmlnq0VACoqcO3ByKx9DRCBcGrT4bYa8Wu4oJCwiCioAIyYcboGDGkAQt3n8wAWtBAARuTsorRgaYLxTY6MaQAi7CkyFo6AA7jAwGRRGlcBsAPRwiAAdQhAGspLhYMhjPNaIgIeBUAA1cDsEAPMi0Q5YHZINAAOlIFEytF49PZtL2%20zkCnoFyuH1xQRC6QAzAAGNJRTFcKQwSn0sgwczcZT4sCEkmmcmU-aRXC4BEQToADxoCEp8xgECkNxgoIgdod7BmCEkwFo00eJHMm3A0HgdNQACYjjpCMpjHzLtdWHdvWQXm8Pl8aj90gCgSCIODIdDYQajSMAMoBxBkEBmWQ262oYIQVHIe0QOskaAoADkrpAMlugIgMAeACtaGxWNamVQSqQWBwuDLsTM1QgCWBiaSdbRQzTA3tGeQp3Q2Rzd2hgzyvPzzoKFktWL8JVL9Qu5QqlSrl6v19qKVvIkA)

```
 var company = {
    fullName: function({name, address, ceo, teamcount}: {
        name: string;
        address: string;
        ceo: string;
        teamcount: string;
    }): string {
        return "Name :- " + name + "\nAddress:- " + address + "\nCEO :- " + ceo + "\nTeamCount :- " + teamcount;
        }
    }

var company1 = {
    name:"BOB the bulider",
    address: "Disney world"
}

// Works
const temporaryVariable1 = company.fullName({...company1, ceo:"BOB", teamcount: "30"})
console.log(temporaryVariable1)

// Example to show how it prevent bug
var company2 = {
    test:"BOB the bulider",
    address: "Disney world"
}

// TS complains, so you know you can't pass this objectto fullName function
const temporaryVariable2 = company.fullName({...company2, ceo:"BOB", teamcount: "30"})

console.log(temporaryVariable2)
```

**NOTE**
Even though the accepted answer works fine, it defeats the purpose of using typescript. The function is still bugy.